# Retrieving XmlNode SelectSingleNode Parents Node

Tags: c#, xml

stack overflow has helped me a ton and decided to join and ask a question myself.

My process that I am trying to do is basically select a node out of an XML document and delete the entire node that the user had selected.

Now for some code!

```
int index = index = list_serverlist.SelectedIndex;
string selectedItem = list_serverlist.Items[index].ToString();

XmlNode selectedNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ServerList/Server/ServerName[text()='" + selectedItem + "']");

selectedNode.ParentNode.RemoveAll();
doc.Save(filePath);
```

Also the XML file that I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServerList>
  <Server>
    <ServerName>FAB13-HST01</ServerName>
    <ServerIP>wasd</ServerIP>
    <ServerUsername>..\Administrator</ServerUsername>
    <ServerPassword>wasd</ServerPassword>
  </Server>
  <Server>
    <ServerName>FAB13-HST02</ServerName>
    <ServerIP>wasd</ServerIP>
    <ServerUsername>..\Administrator</ServerUsername>
    <ServerPassword>wasd</ServerPassword>
  </Server>
  <Server>
    <ServerName>FAB13-HST03</ServerName>
    <ServerIP>wasd</ServerIP>
    <ServerUsername>..\Administrator</ServerUsername>
    <ServerPassword>wasd</ServerPassword>
  </Server>
</ServerList>
```

Now how I see that code happening is...

basically I get what the user selected out of the ListBox make it a string and than select the single node that has that in the ServerName field. Which when debugging seems to work fine.

However when I use the command

```
selectedNode.ParentNode.RemoveAll();
```

It deletes all childs of the node, and not including the parent null. When I debug it and try to get the Parent it seems to be returning null for some odd reason and can't figure out why.

New to XML so not sure what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to get the parent after calling RemoveAll(), the selected node no longer exists.

To remove the whole server element, you could use something like.

```
    XmlNode nodeParent = selectedNode.ParentNode;
    nodeParent.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeParent);
```

Comment: Thanks man that seemed to work. weird i thought it would of gotten the parent node first and THAN removed all. Guess not. Thanks though that got me passed a main problem! Helped a ton!

Comment: Can you add a vote to the answer? I need the points to commit in another forum. Thenks!

Comment: Came back to accept as answer. Thanks again for this. It has been a long while since this problem and I have learned a since this!